# Missing { inserted. <to be read again> error

Tags: math-mode, errors

The following line of code generates an error message:

```
(IC1) $\int_{\underline{v}}^{\bar{v}} (q^i\*y^i (t,v)\*v - p^i (t,v))G(v\mid t)$
\textgreater  
$\int_{\underline{v}}^{\bar{v}}(q^i\*y^i(t^',v)\*v - p^i(t^',v))G(v \mid t)$\
```

The error I get is:

```
Refunds.tex
31
Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   ^
l.31 ...t_{\underline{v}}^{\bar{v}}(q^i \* y^i(t^'
                                                  ,v) \* v - p^i(t^',v))G(v ...
```

Comment: Please always show the full error message which pinpoint sthe exact point of error

Comment: `t^'` doesn't work. Either use `t'` or `t^{'}` depending on the wanted output.

Answer (score 3):

You're problem is that you have `t^'`. For primes you don't need the explicit superscripting and instead just write `t'` -- although, if you like you can write `$t^\prime$`.

A full [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

  (IC1) $\int_{\underline{v}}^{\bar{v}} (q^i\*y^i (t,v)\*v - p^i (t,v))G(v\mid t)$
\textgreater
$\int_{\underline{v}}^{\bar{v}}(q^i\*y^i(t',v)\*v - p^i(t',v))G(v \mid t)$\

\end{document}
```